# How To Insert multiple values from a single form at once using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post

I trying to insert multiple names with their corresponding surnames   in mysql using php but it seems like there is something am doing wrong . I tried google and this site but i have not yet got the best answer to suit my requirements .I also managed to insert them but the surnames could go to a wrong username then I decided to delete that code and start a new one .Any help will be highly appreciated .below is what I tried .

```
 <form action ="dependant_Process_Trevor.php?memberid=<?php echo $_GET['memberid']; ?>" name="contactform"  method="post" id ="---contactform" >
               <input type="hidden" name ="memberid" value="<?php echo $_GET['memberid']; ?>" >
                <div class="box-header">
                </div>
            <!-- Start Trevor -->
              <div class="box box-danger">
                <div class="box-header with-border">
                  <h3 class="box-title">Dependents / Children under the age of 18 years - maximum 6 children</h3>
                </div>
                    <!-- First child -->
                <div class="box-body">
                  <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                      <input type="text" name ="name[]"class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                      <input type="text" name ="surname[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Surname">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-5">
                    <label>parent_type</label>
                   <select  name ="parent_type[]" "> 
                       <option  value ="" >Select Type</option>
                      <option name ="parent_type[]" value ="Son">Son</option>
                      <option name ="parent_type[]" value ="Daughter">Daughter</option>
                      <option name ="parent_type[]" value ="Brother">Brother</option>
                      <option name ="parent_type[]" value ="Grandchild">Grandchild</option>
                      <option name ="parent_type[]" value ="Nephew">Nephew</option>
                      <option name ="parent_type[]" value ="Niece">Niece</option>

                    </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div><!-- /.box-body -->
                <!-- End second  child -->

                    <!-- Start second child -->
                <div class="box-body">
                  <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-xs-3">
                      <input type="text" name ="name[]"class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                      <input type="text" name ="surname[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Surname">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-5">
                    <label>parent_type</label>
                   <select  name ="parent_type[]" "> 
                       <option  value ="" >Select Type</option>
                     <option name ="parent_type[]" value ="Son">Son</option>
                      <option name ="parent_type[]" value ="Daughter">Daughter</option>
                      <option name ="parent_type[]" value ="Brother">Brother</option>
                      <option name ="parent_type[]" value ="Grandchild">Grandchild</option>
                      <option name ="parent_type[]" value ="Nephew">Nephew</option>
                      <option name ="parent_type[]" value ="Niece">Niece</option>

                    </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div><!-- /.box-body -->
                <!-- End second  child -->
                    <!-- Third  child -->
                <div class="box-body">
                  <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-xs-3">
                      <input type="text" name ="name[]"class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                      <input type="text" name ="surname[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Surname">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-5">
                    <label>parent_type</label>
                   <select  name ="parent_type[]" "> 
                       <option  value ="" >Select Type</option>
                     <option name ="parent_type[]" value ="Son">Son</option>
                      <option name ="parent_type[]" value ="Daughter">Daughter</option>
                      <option name ="parent_type[]" value ="Brother">Brother</option>
                      <option name ="parent_type[]" value ="Grandchild">Grandchild</option>
                      <option name ="parent_type[]" value ="Nephew">Nephew</option>
                      <option name ="parent_type[]" value ="Niece">Niece</option>

                    </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div><!-- /.box-body -->
                <!-- End third   child -->

                <!-- Fourth child -->
                <div class="box-body">
                  <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                      <input type="text" name ="name[]"class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                      <input type="text" name ="surname[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Surname">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-5">
                    <label>parent_type</label>
                   <select  name ="parent_type[]" "> 
                       <option  value ="" >Select Type</option>
                       <option name ="parent_type[]" value ="Son">Son</option>
                      <option name ="parent_type[]" value ="Daughter">Daughter</option>
                      <option name ="parent_type[]" value ="Brother">Brother</option>
                      <option name ="parent_type[]" value ="Grandchild">Grandchild</option>
                      <option name ="parent_type[]" value ="Nephew">Nephew</option>
                      <option name ="parent_type[]" value ="Niece">Niece</option>

                    </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div><!-- /.box-body -->
                <!-- End second  child -->

                    <!-- Fifth child -->
                <div class="box-body">
                  <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-xs-3">
                      <input type="text" name ="name[]"class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                      <input type="text" name ="surname[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Surname">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-5">
                    <label>parent_type</label>
                   <select  name ="parent_type[]" "> 
                       <option  value ="" >Select Type</option>
                       <option name ="parent_type[]" value ="Son">Son</option>
                      <option name ="parent_type[]" value ="Daughter">Daughter</option>
                      <option name ="parent_type[]" value ="Brother">Brother</option>
                      <option name ="parent_type[]" value ="Grandchild">Grandchild</option>
                      <option name ="parent_type[]" value ="Nephew">Nephew</option>
                      <option name ="parent_type[]" value ="Niece">Niece</option>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div><!-- /.box-body -->
                <!-- End fifth  child -->
                    <!-- six  child -->
                <div class="box-body">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                      <input type="text" name ="name[]"class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                      <input type="text" name ="surname[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Surname">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-5">
                    <label>parent_type</label>
                   <select  name ="parent_type[]" "> 
                       <option  value ="" >Select Type</option>
                      <option name ="parent_type[]" value ="Son">Son</option>
                      <option name ="parent_type[]" value ="Daughter">Daughter</option>
                      <option name ="parent_type[]" value ="Brother">Brother</option>
                      <option name ="parent_type[]" value ="Grandchild">Grandchild</option>
                      <option name ="parent_type[]" value ="Nephew">Nephew</option>
                      <option name ="parent_type[]" value ="Niece">Niece</option>

                    </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div><!-- /.box-body -->
                <!-- End six  child -->

              </div><!-- /.box -->
              <!-- End  Trevor -->  

                <div class="box-body">
                  <!-- Date dd/mm/yyyy -->
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <div class="input-group-addon">
                      </div>
                    </div><!-- /.input group -->
                  </div><!-- /.form group -->

<input type="submit" name ="submit" value ="Save Data" class="btn-primary">
</form>
```

below is my php

```
//$surname =(isset($_POST['surname']))? trim ($_POST['surname']):'';
$recieved_by =($_SESSION['username']);
$othername =(isset($_POST['othername']))? trim ($_POST['othername']):'';
$gender =(isset($_POST['gender']))? trim ($_POST['gender']):'';
//$parent_type =(isset($_POST['parent_type']))? trim ($_POST['parent_type']):'';
$id_passport =(isset($_POST['id_passport']))? trim ($_POST['id_passport']):'';
$tel =(isset($_POST['tel']))? trim ($_POST['tel']):'';
$work_contact =(isset($_POST['work_contact']))? trim ($_POST['work_contact']):'';
$address =(isset($_POST['address']))? trim ($_POST['address']):'';
$work_address =(isset($_POST['work_address']))? trim ($_POST['work_address']):'';
$comments =(isset($_POST['comments']))? trim ($_POST['comments']):'';
$cell =(isset($_POST['cell']))? trim ($_POST['cell']):'';
//cell convert to 27 


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
foreach($_POST['name'] as $name)
foreach ($_POST['surname'] as $surname)
foreach($_POST['parent_type'] as $parent_type )


$count = count($_POST['name']);

if(is_array($name) && is_array($surname) && is_array($parent_type)) {

    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {


//$name =  $_POST['name'][$i], $_POST['surname'][$i] , $_POST['parent_type'][$i];
//echo $name; 
///
#########################################################
$query ='INSERT INTO dependants(
name, surname, othername, gender, id_passport, 
cell, tel, work_contact, address, work_address, comments, 
memberid,companyid, joined_date, usercode, recieved_by , deadalive
)
VALUES
(
:name, :surname, :othername, :gender, :id_passport, 
:cell, :tel, :work_contact, :address, :work_address, :comments, 
:memberid,:companyid, :joined_date, :usercode, :recieved_by ,:deadalive
)';
$insert=$con->prepare($query);
$insert->execute(array(
':name'=>$name,
':surname'=>$surname,
':othername'=>$othername,
':gender'=>$gender,
':id_passport'=>$id_passport,
':cell'=>$realcell,
':tel'=>$tel,
':work_contact'=>$work_contact,
':address'=>$address,
':work_address'=>$work_address,
':comments'=>$comments,
':memberid'=>$memberid,
':usercode'=>$usercode,
':joined_date'=>$joined_date,
':companyid'=>$companyid,
':recieved_by'=>$recieved_by,
':deadalive'=>$deadalive
));
}}}

if($query){
echo '<h1 style="color:green">Dependant Created</h1>';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly got the answer by the help of @Nigel Ren , all is fine am sorted here is the answer .

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
$name = $_POST['name'] ;
$parent_type = $_POST['parent_type'];
$count = count($_POST['name']);

if(is_array($name) && is_array($surname) && is_array($parent_type)) {
    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
     var_dump($name[$i]);

$surname1 = $surname[$i];
$name1 =$name[$i];
$parent_type1 = $parent_type[$i];

///
#########################################################
$query ='INSERT INTO dependants(
name, surname, othername, gender, id_passport, 
cell, tel, work_contact, address, work_address, comments, 
memberid,companyid, joined_date, usercode, recieved_by , deadalive,parent_type
)
VALUES
(
:name, :surname, :othername, :gender, :id_passport, 
:cell, :tel, :work_contact, :address, :work_address, :comments, 
:memberid,:companyid, :joined_date, :usercode, :recieved_by ,:deadalive,:parent_type
)';
$insert=$con->prepare($query);
$insert->execute(array(
':name'=>$name1,
':surname'=>$surname1,
':othername'=>$othername,
':gender'=>$gender,
':id_passport'=>$id_passport,
':cell'=>$realcell,
':tel'=>$tel,
':parent_type'=>$parent_type1,
':work_contact'=>$work_contact,
':address'=>$address,
':work_address'=>$work_address,
':comments'=>$comments,
':memberid'=>$memberid,
':usercode'=>$usercode,
':joined_date'=>$joined_date,
':companyid'=>$companyid,
':recieved_by'=>$recieved_by,
':deadalive'=>$deadalive
));
}}}// all end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there are a few problems, the first is most of this code is redundant...

```
foreach($_POST['name'] as $name)
foreach ($_POST['surname'] as $surname)
foreach($_POST['parent_type'] as $parent_type )


$count = count($_POST['name']);
```

As the `foreach()` has no `{}` all the loops will eventually just execute the last line, which will always be the same.  So remove the 3 `foreach()` loops and just have

```
$count = count($_POST['name']);
```

Then to set the values for each loop, you almost had it (I think) and need...

```
$name =  $_POST['name'][$i];
$surname = $_POST['surname'][$i];
```

Finally your test to see if it has worked

```
if($query){
```

is incorrect, you should check that all of the

```
$insert->execute(array(...));
```

statements return `true` and this should show that they have all been created.

Comment: Can you please compile the entire code as a single unit instead of part part .I appreciate your effort sir thanks a lot

Comment: There isn't much to it, I would have thought being able to make the few changes was much easier than huge chunks of code.

Comment: i made changes and it inserted array text and it gave me this error : Array to string conversion in . I think that is now my problem since you managed to drive me to the solution .

Comment: One thing is if you can identify the line with the error, it's easier to find out whats causing it - if you need error reporting - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Comment: I think we have now to convert the array in real names not to post the words Array in the bd

Comment: Not sure what that means, can you show the line of code where the error is.

Comment: the actual line is not the problem , so when i var_dump it only print form me parent_type  and that data is in the drop down so even if i put the $name in the var_dump it will still print parent_type